# VB6 Shell Function - Invalid procedure call or argument shell

Tags: shell, vb6

I am trying to run a shell function to open a file using Notepad.exe

I get the "invalid procedure call or argument shell" error when trying to open a file.

```
Sub OpenTextFile(textfile$)
  Dim txtapp$, arg$
  txtapp = "Notepad.exe"
  textfile = "C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\USA - FLNG\modelout\SUMMER.CFS"
  arg = Trim$(txtapp & " " & Chr$(34) & Trim$(textfile) & Chr$(34))
  ierr = Shell(arg, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your code worked for me. How are you declaring your variables?

Comment: @JP. I posted the declarations. Thanks

Comment: what if you declare the full path to notepad.exe? This could explain why it is working for JP (because notepad's path is in his %path% environment variable, but not yours)

Comment: @SpectralGhost Actually I think it worked for me because the test path I used did not contain spaces.

Comment: The file having spaces shouldn't be an issue because it's wrapped in quotes (Chr$(34)).

Comment: It's more efficient to use a literal for the quotes: `txtapp & " """ & Trim$(textfile) & """"`

Comment: Have you had a chance to try my solution? Would like to know if it worked or if you did something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
Sub OpenTextFile(textfile As String)

Const txtapp As String = "Notepad.exe"
Dim arg As String
Dim ierr As Double

  arg = Trim$(txtapp & " " & Chr$(34) & Trim$(textfile) & Chr$(34))
  ierr = Shell#(arg, vbNormalFocus)

End Sub
```

[Type-declaration characters](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/191713) are considered legacy code, so I avoid them with declarations. (However I used them with Shell/Trim/Chr to avoid the Variant return type.)

I believe the error you are experiencing is because your filepath contains spaces. Try the [WSHOM](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/wsh_objectmodel.mspx?mfr=true) instead:

```
Sub OpenTextFile(textfile As String)
Dim oShell As Object

  Set oShell = GetShell

  If Not oShell Is Nothing Then
    oShell.Run textfile
  End If
End Sub

Function GetShell() As Object
  On Error Resume Next  
  Set GetShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
End Function
```

Comment: Correct use of double quotes should fix the spaces-in-path problem.

Comment: @Tomalak I believe I have correct use of quotes. There are a bunch of shell calls in the program I am currently working on. I would love to not have to change them all.

Comment: @gberg927 Tomalak is right, I believe you need to double-up the quotes if there is a space in the path. However the WSH method is supposed to eliminate the need for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a file Notepad.exe located beside your exe application