# VBA: Howto open a file, that has # -characters in it's name?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an access database front-end, and on a buttonclick, certain files are opening, with the software they are associated with.
The code to achieve this is the following:

```
If (IsNull(Me.filepath)) Then Exit Sub
If (FileFolderExists(Me.filepath)) Then
    If (isFolder(Me.filepath)) Then
        Shell "explorer.exe " & Me.filepath, vbNormalFocus
    Else
        FollowHyperlink Me.filepath
    End If
End If
```

Well, this is all good and working, but the file won't open, if the filename contains # symbols. Wich is unfortunatly the case: Some of the filenames look like this: 13_tamogatodontes##1911_201001.pdf

I tried to find some answers with google, and on msdn, did not found any useful info.
Does somebody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you open this file manually?

Comment: @adamson it looks like the # is treated as a special character can you rename the file as part of this process or check the filename for the pound sign (#) and abort the file open?

Comment: @SteveRobillard Unfortunatly I cannot rename the file, because files named like this are coming from a different company.

Comment: How about `Shell "explorer.exe """ & Me.filepath & "", vbNormalFocus`, that is, quote the name?

Comment: @Remou. I'm new here. How can I accept your answer? I also found a solution here: http://allenbrowne.com/func-GoHyperlink.html , but yours is much simpler.

Comment: @Adamsan Thanks for the thought. I'll put up with being robbed for now :(

Comment: @Remou Ha ha, I was gutted after answering the question, when my page refreshed and showed I was just behind : )

Comment: For another solution, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912905/vb6-shell-function-invalid-procedure-call-or-argument-shell/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose your filename in quotes also, e.g:

```
Shell "explorer.exe " & "" & Me.filepath & "", vbNormalFocus
```

I'm not sure if it's 2 or 3 double quotes but have a play around : )

Comment: It's correct this way, Remou's solution in the comments above is basicly the same:    `Shell "explorer.exe """ & Me.filepath & "", vbNormalFocus`

Comment: @Adamsan : ) He beat me by a few seconds, no worries as long as the solution has been found.