# Accessing a folder with a pound sign (#) in the folder name using VBA

Tags: vba, filepath

The code below works for all folder names except ones with a pound sign. For example:

\\Filestore2\2016 JOBS\CO#2 does not work, but \\Filestore2\2016 JOBS\CONo2 does. But I need to be able to open the ones with #.

```
Application.FollowHyperlink "" & strStartFilePath & strEndFilePath & ""
```

Comment: Have got tried anything like file:/// ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: Instead of a web address like http:\\ try file:\\ maybe?

Comment: Which part of my code contains an implied http? As I stated, the code works fine for all folders except ones with the # symbol, so I'm looking for a way to address that.

Comment: Have you tried adding an additional trailing backslash? Just a thought...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer should be the same as for a question with a marginally different title.

[VBA: Howto open a file, that has # -characters in it's name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971744/vba-howto-open-a-file-that-has-characters-in-its-name)

```
Shell "explorer.exe " ....
```

Comment: I've tried that as well and it didn't work. I simply replaced their `Me.filepath` with my path string.

Comment: Actually it didn't work because my `strEndFilePath` contained double backslashes to make it work for the line of code in my question (it is read as a single backslash when the line is run), but Shell cannot have those double backslashes since it interprets it literally